# JSON string returns NAN

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, nan

I have a web API that returns a JSON result, when I issue a GET request using the API URL, it works OK. But when I call my API from jQuery only one string field returns NAN.

Result:

[image]

```
$.ajax({
                Type: 'GET',
                url: 'api/controller1',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function (data) {
                    var htmlString = '';
                    $(data).each(function (index, data) {
                        var myDate = new Date(data.date);
                        htmlString += '<h3>' + String(myDate) + '</h3><div>'
                            + data.ID + "<br/>" +
                            + data.stringvalue + '</div>';
                    });

                    $('#accordion').html(htmlString).accordion({
                        collapsible: true
                    });
```

I tried the `JSON.Stringify()` method but it returns the same result. I also tried to get the type of the specified value and its string so I don't think I need to parse it or what so on.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your `<br>` tag, you have an extra plus sign. JavaScript can no longer coalesce properly, and tries to use number addition instead of string concatenation, casting your string to NaN.

Comment: Magic, thanks Joshua Miles, it worked now, I look a bit silly now but it took me days to figure out whats going on. Thanks a million.

Comment: My pleasure sir! Glad I could help!